# Android most efficient way to have many views

Tags: java, android

I have an app that will allow the user to drag many views onto a "canvas".  The user can pan, rotate, flip, and scale these views.  Each view will need to have a image on it.  I was thinking of simply inflating imageviews and letting the user interact with those.

Is there a more efficient way to have up to 50 images on screen that can be interacted with?

If so, can you point me to some code examples?

EDIT:

I have noticed there are multiple ways to do this:
Some tutorials use a surfaceview and bitmaps and threads
Other tutorials use open gl
Other tutorials simply have views on views,

What route should I take?

Thanks

Comment: Open GL is for sure the most efficient way, but it is also the one that requires more code. I'd go to the simplest way that allows resizing and modifying the images, then if performance is not acceptable, find a way to optimize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this app:

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sunshine.fingerpaint

By using a Horizontal Scroll View at the top of the application, you could inflate the 50 images you want and let the user interact with them.